# What does a hideaway office or an unmarked haven in the Capitol look like?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives

https://thehill.com/homenews/house/4237209-mchenry-orders-pelosi-to-leave-capitol-office-in-first-acts-as-speaker/ says:

> A small number of senior representatives have “hideaway offices” inside the Capitol Building.

https://www.al.com/news/2023/10/patrick-mchenry-acting-speaker-orders-nancy-pelosi-away-for-feinstein-funeral-to-vacate-hideaway-office.html says:

> A hideaway office is an unmarked haven away from staff, constituents and media.

What does a hideaway office or  an unmarked haven look like?

What does "unmarked" mean here?

How is it different from a regular office? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like any other office, just is unmarked and doesn't list who uses it?

Comment: @JoeW How do you get one from the government ?

Comment: @sfxedit The same way any member of congress gets one. They are assigned one by the leadership of the body that they are a member of likely after they request one.

Answer (score 17):

It's just an office, but whose office it is isn't marked by a sign on its door or in any public maps or registries.

This is in contrast to e.g. the publicly listed offices that Senators and Representatives have in [Congressional office buildings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congressional_office_buildings).

You can find more details if you follow the link in

> A [hideaway office is an unmarked haven](https://www.politico.com/story/2009/01/the-closely-held-secrets-of-hideaways-017760) away from staff, constituents and media.

If you instead followed the link in

> McHenry did order former Speaker Nancy [Pelosi to vacate her Capitol hideaway office by Wednesday](https://www.politico.com/live-updates/2023/10/03/congress/mchenry-pelosi-hideaway-office-house-remove-00119803)

you would even see a picture of the hideaway (apparently, the secret of its location was not really held that closely in this case):

> [image]
> Items are removed from Nancy Pelosi's hideaway office.

("McHenry ordered Pelosi to leave her Capitol hideaway office by Wednesday", by NICHOLAS WU and DANIELLA DIAZ, 10/03/2023, 7:56PM UPDATED: 10/03/2023, 8:48PM ET, *Politico*)